# How not to have dollar sign in target_link_options mangled?

Tags: cmake, escaping, dollar-sign

If I have this CMake script:

```
add_link_options(--preload-file=temp$.txt)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
```

or

```
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_options(main PUBLIC --preload-file=temp$.txt)
```

and an arbitrary file named `temp$.txt`, it doesn't find the txt file because the dollar sign gets changed into something like `\$$` in the actual compiler invocation.

(Don't mind the actual link option, it's an Emscripten specific one, but the problem I believe is not specific to Emscripten development.)

What should I do to make it find my file which has a dollar sign in its name?

Comment: I also see it gets escaped to `\$$` which looks like a bug. It should just be `\$`.

Comment: Here's a link to the CMake issue tracker (I am not affiliated): https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues

Comment: @AlexReinking might these be related? https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/21647 https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/16395

Comment: no, I observe the same behavior with "Unix Makefiles", so it's not Ninja-specific

Comment: I notice that `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` is not affected by the escaping bug. If `temp$.txt` exists before the build, you can set that variable in a toolchain file (otherwise set it in your main CMakeLists.txt with a to-do comment to replace it with `target_link_options` when the bug is fixed).

Comment: Actually, on a second reading, I think #16395 is related.

Comment: @AlexReinking Trying to use `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` I found that `$` still becomes `$$` but not `\$$`. Unfortunately this still does not work.

Comment: I tried it myself and did not observe that behavior with `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`. Can you post repro steps?

Comment: @AlexReinking On a second attempt I've noticed my file path was wrong, and your suggestion is correct. Thanks!

Comment: great! I converted my comment into an answer

Answer (score 1):

The developers [seem to agree this is a bug](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/how-not-to-have-dollar-sign-in-target-link-options-mangled/3939) based on a discussion raised on their Discourse. However, fixing it will require a policy.

In the meantime, I discovered that the `CMAKE_*_LINKER_FLAGS` variables do not suffer from the same bad escaping behavior, so you can set your flag there (preferably in a toolchain file). For executables, the variable is `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`.

Comment: Why is a toolchain file preferable?

Comment: If your code cannot compile on _any_ platform without that flag, then it's fine to put in your CMakeLists.txt. Otherwise, if it isn't an absolute requirement (like a source file, a dependency, etc.), it belongs outside, like in a toolchain file or preset. Since this is emscripten-related (i.e. a compiler), it fits the toolchain description better.